# Toggle function in vim

Tags: function, vim

Basically what I want to do is

```
map ,e :call ToggleEssayMode()<CR>
function! ToggleEssayMode()
if toggle==true
  :map j gj
  :map k gk
  toggle=false
else
  :umap j
  :umap k
  toggle=true
enndfunction
```

I've looked around for a while, but all i could find people using were the reserved vim variables. Can I make my own variable? Is there a more correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unless you use separate functions for enabling and disabling, you will need a flag variable, and in order to isolate this from the rest of your configuration, I would recommend writing a small plugin. For example, create a file `essay.vim` (the actual name is irrelevant, as long as it ends in `.vim`) in `~/.vim/plugin/` with the following content:

```vimscript
let s:enabled = 0

function! ToggleEssayMode()
    if s:enabled
        unmap j
        unmap k
        let s:enabled = 0
    else
        nnoremap j gj
        nnoremap k gk
        let s:enabled = 1
    endif
endfunction
```

The mapping to call `ToggleEssayMode()` can then be in the same file or in your `.vimrc`.

Some remarks about your code:

- Use `let` in order to assign variables (cf. `set` for options).
- Vim does not support `true` and `false`; use `1` and `0` instead.
- Every `if` needs a closing `endif`.
- `umap` should be `unmap`; the former does not exist.
- `nnoremap` should be used in order to avoid recursive mappings.
- `:` is unnecessary before commands in scripts.

Comment: Can you please tell me what `if s:enabled` mean? What is it that the `if-else` part is checking?

Answer (score 1):

Nikita Kouevda's answer helped me piece it together, but I still needed to look a few things up. For posterity, this is the script again:

```
let s:enabled = 0

function! ToggleEssayMode()
    if s:enabled
        unmap j
        unmap k
        let s:enabled = 0
    else
        nnoremap j gj
        nnoremap k gk
        let s:enabled = 1
    endif
endfunction
```

The `s:` part of `s:enabled` indicates it's a variable. If you just do `let enabled = 0` and later `if enabled`, it will error on the `if`.

The function needs to start with a capital letter, for some reason vim enforces that. When I was customizing the function, I ran into that requirement.

To later call your function, you need to use `:call`. For example, `:call ToggleEssayMode()`.

I just placed this in my `.vimrc`, not a plugin folder.

Finally, a protip: use `:so %` to reload your `.vimrc` without restarting vim. It might give a bunch of errors from things that are already defined, but it seems to work anyway.

Comment: The function doesn't need to start with a capital letter. It can also start with `s:`, or be defined in an autoloaded plugin. Actually, it's best to avoid exposing global functions. I gave more details in [an answer on SU](https://superuser.com/questions/147069/vim-plugin-creation-tutorial/147233#147233).

Answer (score 1):

I just provided a shorter one:

```
let s:_toggle=0
function! s:toggleFunc() abort
    let s:_toggle = s:_toggle? 0: 1
    return s:_toggle
endfunction
```

Screenshot (Clickable):

[image]

Comment: Welp. How do you have that cmatrix background? @.@