# VIM : Toggle between two executions for the same remap

Tags: vim, terminal, remap

I'd like to have to same remap to open and close my terminal. 
Here is my remap to open it : `nnoremap <C-s> :bel vert term<CR>`
What I want is that when my terminal is already open, if I type `<C-s>` again, it execute `exit<CR>`
I already tried a function that I found here : [Toggle function in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20579142/toggle-function-in-vim)

```
let s:enable = 0
function! ToggleEasyMode()
    if s:enable
        nnoremap <C-s> exit<CR>
        let s:enable = 0
    else
        nnoremap <C-s> :bel vert term<CR>
        let s:enable = 0
    endif
endfunction
```

Comment: Maybe you should be using `tnoremap` for terminal bindings?

Comment: Unrequested useful information: this is not a "remap(ping)" but a *map(ping)*. Core Vim doesn't come with any mapping so there is nothing to "remap". The confusion may be caused by the "re" in "nnoremap" which is part of "nore", not of an imaginary "remap": `nnoremap` is made of `n` for "normal mode", `nore` for "non-recursive", `map` for… "map (this to that)".

Answer (score 1):

thanks to @ChristianGibbons
**the answer:**

```
nnoremap <C-s> :bel vert term<CR>
tnoremap <C-s> <CR>exit<CR>
```